# Create object access in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Could you please let me know what privilege need to be granted for a oracle user to allow creating, modifying objects in one schema. I do not want to grant the administrator privilege to the user, I just want him access to create objects in a particular schema alone.

will grant all for that schema work ?

Comment: _any_ object? _existing_ objects? _what kind of_ objects? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#sthref8989

Comment: what do you mean with objects? tables, procedures, types?

Comment: Maybe worth taking a look at [Grant create permission on a specific schema in Oracle 11g](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13320/grant-create-permission-on-a-specific-schema-in-oracle-11g) ?

Comment: I want to create new object, delete existing objects....... with all the comments I guess it is not possible to do what I thought of doing.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to grant privileges to a schema, you can only grant privileges on an object.

The `CREATE TABLE` privilege enables the user to create tables within their own schema only.

The `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege allows the user to create tables in any schema.

Comment: my question is can I grant create objects permission to a user ?

Comment: The CREATE TABLE privilege means the user can only create tables within their own schema.

Comment: @Hari, there is no create object privilege. You must say what kind of object you want granted. `create table` ,`create procedure`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming with "create object" you mean `create type ... as object`, then you'll need the `create type` privilege.

This is documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8001.htm#SQLRF01506

> To create a type in your own schema, ***you must have the CREATE TYPE system privilege***. To create a type in another user's schema, you must have the CREATE ANY TYPE system privilege. You can acquire these privileges explicitly or be granted them through a role.
>
> To create a subtype, you must have the UNDER ANY TYPE system privilege or the UNDER object privilege on the supertype.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>